# MySQL not responding for simple queries when using INNER JOIN. especially "Sending data" takes too much time

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables; `songs` with 48 959 281 rows, and `popular_songs` with 5 721 117  rows.

This is structure of that two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE songs (
  songId       BIGINT(20)    NOT NULL,
  songName     VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
  songDuration BIGINT(20)    NOT NULL,
  songPreview  VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (songId),
  INDEX (songDuration)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE popular_songs (
  storeFrontId BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  genreId      BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  songId       BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  songRank     INT(11)    NOT NULL,
  INDEX (storeFrontId),
  INDEX (genreId),
  INDEX (songId),
  INDEX (songRank),
  CONSTRAINT popular_song UNIQUE (storeFrontId, genreId, songId),
  FOREIGN KEY (storeFrontId) REFERENCES storefront (storeFrontId),
  FOREIGN KEY (genreId) REFERENCES genre (genreId),
  FOREIGN KEY (songId) REFERENCES songs (songId)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

When I'm running this below two quires everything works fine.

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM songs;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 48959281 |
+----------+
1 row in set (9.10 sec)

mysql> SHOW PROFILE;
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000008 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000002 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000019 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000003 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000011 |
| System lock                    | 0.000004 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000017 |
| init                           | 0.000006 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000003 |
| statistics                     | 0.000004 |
| preparing                      | 0.000004 |
| executing                      | 0.000003 |
| Sending data                   | 9.100444 |
| end                            | 0.000012 |
| query end                      | 0.000005 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000008 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000007 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000002 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000012 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000002 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000001 |
| storing result in query cache  | 0.000002 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000001 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000003 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM popular_songs;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  5721117 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.34 sec)

mysql> SHOW PROFILE;
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000012 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000004 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000037 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000006 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000017 |
| System lock                    | 0.000007 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000031 |
| init                           | 0.000010 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000017 |
| statistics                     | 0.000004 |
| preparing                      | 0.000004 |
| executing                      | 0.000003 |
| Sending data                   | 1.343991 |
| end                            | 0.000010 |
| query end                      | 0.000005 |
| closing tables                 | 0.000007 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000007 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000002 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000011 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000001 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000001 |
| storing result in query cache  | 0.000002 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000001 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000003 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I'm running these below queries MySQL is not responding. I don't understand what the reason is.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM songs
INNER JOIN popular_songs ON popular_songs.songId = songs.songId
```

---

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM songs
INNER JOIN popular_songs ON popular_songs.songId = songs.songId
WHERE songs.songDuration > 0
```

**Update:**

MySQL responded with above two queries. But it takes 250-300 seconds on `Sending data`. How to optimize this.

**EXPLAIN EXTENDED report:**

```
mysql> EXPLAIN EXTENDED
    -> SELECT COUNT(*)
    -> FROM songs
    -> INNER JOIN popular_songs ON popular_songs.songId = songs.songId;
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref                         | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | popular_songs | index  | songId        | songRank | 4       | NULL                        | 6449163 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | songs         | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY  | 8       | itunes.popular_songs.songId |       1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+----------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN EXTENDED
    -> SELECT COUNT(*)
    -> FROM songs
    -> INNER JOIN popular_songs ON popular_songs.songId = songs.songId
    -> WHERE songs.songDuration > 0;
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+----------------------+----------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys        | key      | key_len | ref                         | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+----------------------+----------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | popular_songs | index  | songId               | songRank | 4       | NULL                        | 6449163 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | songs         | eq_ref | PRIMARY,songDuration | PRIMARY  | 8       | itunes.popular_songs.songId |       1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+----------------------+----------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

**When using INDEX `songId` for joing two tables:**

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM songs INNER JOIN popular_songs USE INDEX FOR JOIN (songId) ON popular_songs.songId = songs.songId;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|  5721117 |
+----------+
1 row in set (25.35 sec)

mysql> SHOW PROFILE;
+--------------------------------+-----------+
| Status                         | Duration  |
+--------------------------------+-----------+
| starting                       |  0.000011 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   |  0.000004 |
| checking query cache for query |  0.000045 |
| checking permissions           |  0.000004 |
| checking permissions           |  0.000004 |
| Opening tables                 |  0.000023 |
| System lock                    |  0.000007 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   |  0.000030 |
| init                           |  0.000021 |
| optimizing                     |  0.000011 |
| statistics                     |  0.000020 |
| preparing                      |  0.000012 |
| executing                      |  0.000005 |
| Sending data                   | 25.350160 |
| end                            |  0.000019 |
| query end                      |  0.000005 |
| closing tables                 |  0.000024 |
| freeing items                  |  0.000022 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   |  0.000002 |
| freeing items                  |  0.000016 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   |  0.000001 |
| freeing items                  |  0.000001 |
| storing result in query cache  |  0.000002 |
| logging slow query             |  0.000001 |
| logging slow query             |  0.000005 |
| cleaning up                    |  0.000003 |
+--------------------------------+-----------+
26 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It's pretty nice. But, still it's take 25 seconds on `Sending data`.

**Explain extended for above query:**

```
mysql> EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT COUNT(*) FROM songs INNER JOIN popular_songs USE INDEX FOR JOIN (songId) ON popular_songs.songId = songs.songId;
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                         | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | popular_songs | index  | songId        | songId  | 8       | NULL                        | 2684407 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | songs         | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | itunes.popular_songs.songId |       1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------+---------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Well, your query seems correct.. whats the relation between the tables? 1-1 1-n n-n n-1 ? maybe this is just a very heavy query

Comment: Do you really need to have a separate table for popular songs? Can't you just have an extra column in the songs table that indicates it's a popular song?

Comment: @Thilo if mysql cannot process the query, it is unlikely to be able to produce a query plan (explain). In mysql the 2 are very much related.

Comment: @Shadow: Really? That's lame....

Comment: @Thilo accuracy vs performance. Mysql went for as much accuracy as possible.

Comment: @Shadow: That does not make much sense. Before a query can be executed, it has to be planned. You should be able to get that plan without running the query (of course, it will only contain row estimates and no timings, but you can see which indexes would be used etc). In other databases, you have EXPLAIN and EXPLAIN ANALYZE for these two modes.

Comment: `...WHERE songs.songDuration > 0` can a duration be 0 or less?

Comment: "MySQL should be able to figure that out" - I would not be surprised if MySQL can't. What about `popular_songs STRIGHT_JOIN songs`?

Comment: Woah, you just added `WHERE songs.songDuration > 0`. That changes everything....

Comment: @Thilo mysql has explain, but mysql by default configuration tries to update stats when explain is run to provide more adequate results. This is going to take a lot of time. Unless the OP has the right to turn this feature off.

Comment: @Thilo It's not responding with and without `WHERE songs.songDuration > 0`

Comment: Hi friends, question updated. Please take a look :)

Comment: Well, then you can give us the EXPLAIN EXTENDED output.

Comment: @Thilo added EXPLAIN EXTENDED report to question

Comment: Can you try this query: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM popular_songs INNER JOIN songs ON songs.songId = popular_songs.songId;` and post execution plan?

Comment: @MilanTomeš I'm executed your query. Same issue.

Comment: Why 'BIGINT' for song duration anyway? That is some very long songs. In fact if the whole world could crowd-source-listen to one song it would take the whole population all of their lives + 20% more to finish it. [see calculation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bwqgyyzys2aa949/bigint-pop2.png?dl=1) — perhaps BIGINT for index is not the problem, but it is a horrible data representation.

Comment: @Michael Hi friend, thanks for nice calculation. It's really useful. I will change to `INT` :)

Comment: It's pretty strange, that optimizer chooses `songRank` key for popular_songs even it correctly evaluates `songId` key as available. Can you try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM songs  INNER JOIN popular_songs USE INDEX FOR JOIN (songId) ON popular_songs.songId = songs.songId;`?

Comment: @MilanTomeš Thanks for your nice suggestion. It's completed in 25 seconds. Question updated with results. But it still takes too much time on `sending data`.

Comment: I'm wondering why are you executing this query, because same result gives you simple `select count(*) from popular_songs` because there is a foreign key to `songs`. So in reality - are you using another condition? BTW when you try to execute `select count(*) from popular_songs` how long it takes?

Comment: @Shadow, @Thilo -- in older versions of MySQL, `EXPLAIN` would completely evaluate _subqueries_.  But the OP has no subqueries.

Comment: Adding `duration>0` means that it cannot perform the query just in the index.  So it is necessarily slower.

Comment: `FOREIGN KEYs` are irrelevant to these queries.

Comment: @MilanTomeš, @ChandraNakka - The order of tables in an `INNER JOIN` does not control what order the Optimizer picks for performing the query.  Check the `EXPLAIN`.  Any change in timings is cause by other factors.

Comment: Have you tried optimizing the server, instead of the tables/database (that seems to be optimized for these queries)? I mean, what is the memory available, the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, etc? If you go reading data from disk you will get  really slow queries...

Comment: Why BIGINT for the primary keys? You have ~ 1/40th of the number of rows that could be represented with an unsigned INT (and 1/80th if you switched to an unsigned INT). Using BIGINT just seems to be greatly increasing the sizes of your indexes with no likely benefit.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that the index on `songDuration` is confusing the optimizer.  You might try phrasing the query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM songs s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM popular_songs ps
              WHERE ps.songId = s.songId
             ) AND
      s.songDuration > 0;
```

The index on `songDuration` would be better to include `songId` as well:  `songs(songDuration, songId)`.

Comment: Your query is also not working. I mean MySQL not responding with this query.

Comment: Did you create the proposed new index?

Answer (score 4):

It picked `songRank` because it was the smallest index (`INT`, not `BIGINT`).

"Sending data" is one of about 2 useless things that come from that tool.  Since it rarely provides anything useful, I don't use it.

Often timing is confusing because of caching.  You appear to have the Query cache turned off (good).  If the data (or index) is not currently cached in RAM (InnoDB's buffer_pool), the timings are inflated due to I/O.  The times you have look like they were CPU bound.  Running a query twice avoids the I/O question.

There are several things to do to shrink the tables; this tends to make them run faster.

`popular_songs` has not explicit `PRIMARY KEY`, so a 6-byte PK was invented.  Since you have `CONSTRAINT popular_song UNIQUE (storeFrontId, genreId, songId)`, that is a 'natural' PK.  Get rid of the constraint and add that as the PK.  (We may need to rearrange the columns; we'll see.)

Use `INT UNSIGNED`, not `BIGINT` for all the ids; that cuts the size in half.

`songRank` allows -2 billion to + 2 billion and occupies 4 bytes.  You can probably find a smaller field, and may want to use `UNSIGNED`.  For example, `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` is 2 bytes and allows values 0..65535.

As already mentioned, `songDuration` is using too big a field (unless it is measured in nanoseconds).

`INDEX (storeFrontId)` is redundant with the `UNIQUE` index, so it could be removed.

But the real issue is that the tables are big, and `JOINs` cost something.  I do not think you can get the queries to run much faster than what you are seeing.

That leads to another question -- why do these queries matter?  They sound like one-time queries, not something that a user sitting at a UI is waiting for every day.  When dealing with long-running queries against large tables, it is often best to re-think the requirements.

If the queries are repeatedly being performed, can't they be run once a day and 'cached'?  I suspect the tables are not growing by more than 1% per day, implying that the result sets will be correct to about 1%; isn't that "close enough"?

If there are other purposes for the queries, perhaps we can come up with a different way to solve the real problem.

Answer (score 3):

Note that select count(*) from table is actually not reading the table at all. It is picking any available unique index (e.g. a primary key), and return the number of rows in that index (which in fact is equal to the number of the rows of a table).

However as soon as you join two tables, data has to be read. You have huge data, it makes sense to perform the join and the where criteria from the indexes instead of reading in all the data from the disk.

- popular_songs.songid shall be also a primary key

This helps on SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM songs
INNER JOIN popular_songs ON popular_songs.songId = songs.songId

- song.songDuration must have a non-unique index, otherwise you read all 48 million records just to evaluate the where criteria. (this you already have)

This helps on SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM songs
INNER JOIN popular_songs ON popular_songs.songId = songs.songId
WHERE songs.songDuration > 0

- avoid where criterias with low cardinality

songDuration is mostly some number, for very few songs it is zero. Therefore using it as a where criteria will not use the index (you had to force the index yourselves). It is better idea to have a boolean field telling if the song has zero duration (is zero length song a valid use case? I guess not? The songDuration can be a nullable field and contain null if the duratiuon is not known.) But if you go for the boolean field or a 0/1 field, you can benefit of bitmap indexes if your database supports that.

Some rules of thumb: avoid reading data from the tables if not needed:

- prefer **unique indexes** over non-unique indexes
- if you join two tables, the **joining column** in both tables **must have an index.** If you can have unique indexes that is better, if the column is actually the primary key it is the best.
- all columns in the **where criterias** must be **indexed**. Otherwise to evaluate the where criteria, all rows must be read from the disk.
- use **compound indexes** if possibe. E.g. if you want to speed up a query which contains **where songId=xxx and genre=yyy** then make one index which contains *both* songid *AND* genre instead of indexing the columns individually. This particular index can be a unique index, since songId is unique - reading data from unique indexes is faster
- indexing columns **in advance**, and indexing individual columns usually makes no sense, it is a **premature optimization**. Indexes are for speeding up your queries, and you have queries once you have an application. Then you can see which query is slow, and speed it up using the methods above.
- **avoid of** adding all kinds of possible indexes just "because it might be good at some point". Indexes makes selects quick, but slows update and insert and delete statements.

Answer (score 2):

It depends very much on your search criteria. If you want to search over song.songDuration try to create composite index:

```
ALTER TABLE song ADD INDEX songDuration (songId, songDuration);
```

That way the MySQL optimizer will use only the index instead of searching for the row just to fetch songId.

Also you could try to set the isolation level of **READ UNCOMMITED**, if you think your result set could live with that. It will speed up your query a lot!

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
```

#### EDIT

I have missed that you are **storing huge VARCHAR**s inside the table. I'm currently not working on MySQL but I remember that MySQL keeps the whole VARCHAR inside the table no matter what size it is. You could improve the performance a lot if change a songPreview to **TEXT** type for example.

TEXT, BLOB and CBLOB fields are kept outside the table, so the join and search by other fields should permorms better.

If you really think there are much songs with title around 1000 characters you could also make songName **TEXT** type and use a [**FULLTEXT index**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) to search. If your song titles are not do big, you could use CHAR just to keep the row size fixed and to improve the table performance.

You could read more about why to use TEXT against large VARCHAR here [High Performance MySQL](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9781449332471/ch04.html)

About [**FULLTEXT index**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-fulltext-index.html) search - I have used it in real project over TEXT field, so I could confirm it performs better than VARCHAR with LIKE.

Your tables are really huge, so if you want to change the types from VARCHAR(1000) to TEXT do not alter the table. It will perform better if you create new tables and copy the data in new tables. Altering the old one will take forever. You could speedup the process if you don't create indexes and constraints at the table definition but after the old data is copied inside the table.

Comment: The tables are InnoDB, so whether the large `VARCHARs` are kept with the record or not depends on `ROW_FORMAT`, which currently has 4 choices.  If (and that is a signifcant 'if') the table can be cached in the buffer_pool, then whether the text fields are inline or not does not matter for _these_ queries.

Comment: Do _not_ use `CHAR`.  `FIXED` length records is an old wives' tale that no longer applies.

Comment: There is no substantive advantage in changing `VARCHAR` to `TEXT`.

Comment: `ALTER` is as fast (with few exceptions) as copying manually.  After all, `ALTER` performs the steps you mention!.  Furthermore, in later versions, some `ALTERs` are done in the background, thereby not interfering with other operations.

Comment: It was a long time I have been using MySQL for last time. It looks like VARCHAR are now stored outside the table. Since in the particular example it is used to keep the song text in here, there is no any point to not store it into text field. Also VARCHAR consumes really a lot of memory when building the temporary result set. It was and still is like that, so it could drow down the performance a lot.

Comment: I haven't found anything changed about the huge table alter performance. Still the better way is to create a new table and insert the old data.

Comment: Seems the current way the VARCHAR is strored in InnoDB is more similar to DB2 - small part of the VARCHAR is kept in the row and the overflow part is kept outside the table. DB2 has mechanism to define how much of VARCHAR you want in the table row (ALLOCATE). It speeds up table lookups a lot. So I still suggest - keep the song name in CHAR to allocate the space and keep the song text in TEXT, to ensure it will not eat your server memory when you do searches.

Comment: I don't see `songText`, but it might be better to put that in a parallel table.  InnoDB has 4 Row_formats, some keep non of the bulky things with the row; some keep the first 767 bytes; you do not get to choose how much or which to do (other than picking the Row_format).

Comment: But definitely `VARCHAR` in preference to `CHAR`.  `CHAR` simply wastes space, especially for English text in `CHARSET utf8`.

Comment: In a complex `SELECT`, `TEXT` and `VARCHAR(512 or more)` force disk-based tmp table instead of `MEMORY` table.  This is about the only substantive difference between `TEXT` and `VARCHAR(<512)`.

Answer (score 1):

`popular_songs` table has no `PRIMARY KEY`. I would suggest changing `CONSTRAINT popular_song UNIQUE (storeFrontId, genreId, songId)` into `PRIMARY KEY (songId, genreId, storeFrontId)`. Please note the change of fields order too.

Optimizer should take care of it, but I still would put smaller table at the front of the `Join` like Milan Tomeš suggested:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM popular_songs
INNER JOIN songs ON songs.songId = popular_songs.songId
                AND songs.songDuration > 0
```

Also, I don't know what the goal is, but to me it is begging for Count Distinct:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT popular_songs.songId)
FROM popular_songs
INNER JOIN songs ON songs.songId = popular_songs.songId
                AND songs.songDuration > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`count(*)` is quicker if the query does not have `join` and `where` clauses.

> COUNT(*) is optimized to return very quickly if the SELECT retrieves
>   from one table, no other columns are retrieved, and there is no WHERE
>   clause.

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count).

Since you do not seem to have the option of getting rid of the `join` and `where` from your query, Gordon Linoff's answer seems to be a nice optimization. However, if the number of rows is practically infinite, then even with that query you will have to wait a lot, especially due to the fact that there is still a `where` clause both in the select and subselect.

My proposed solution is to have a saved value for the result of that query and increment/decrement it when you know the amount of elements to be included/excluded and recalculate it when you do not know the amount of elements to be added/removed. Whenever you need this count, just use that scalar value instead of querying.

Answer (score 0):

Because we have foreign key between `songs`and `popular_songs`, why do we need to inner join and count?, it's overkill, if you want to count number of unique popular songs, this query is enough:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct(songId))
FROM popular_songs
```

With more duration conditon

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (SELECT distinct(songId) as songId FROM popular_songs) as t
    JOIN songs on t.songId = songs.songId
WHERE songs.songDuration > 0
```